Setuptools-based pip install with no-build-isolation-package
I am trying to create a simple pyproject.toml file where I can disable disable build isolation for a specific dependency. The idea is that a the install process should install setuptools if this is missing, and check that another dependency (which requires manual installation) is already present. uv tools seem to offer something like this (see here), but I'd like to stick to "basic" pip.
Note: I saw that pip provides a --no-build-isolation flag, but this would also affect the setuptools requirement, wouldn't it?

Not possible with pip. There is not standard specification for this. I had no idea uv offered this, it's probably the only tool that has this feature.
